# Clicking a shared link from my site on facebook doesn't take me to my website, it opens my app

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Having trouble solving this one.. hoping someone out there has run into it and can help.

Scenario:
I'm the owner/developer of an iOS app (https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1032962936)
It integrates with Facebook for facebook login so i have a facebook app in place to service the API requests.
I also run a website to support the app (http://www.heythere.us) and that site has a blog.

The Problem Statement:
When I share a blog article from my site to facebook it shares perfectly fine.  It shows the right thumbnail image from the blog article, and the right text.  All of that is good to go because i installed the official facebook plugin for wordpress.  However, I have the iOS app installed on my iphone, and i click the shared article in my facebook feed my phone just opens my app when it should be opening safari and sending me to my website's blog article.  It's almost like there's some deep linking going on here that isn't quite right.  Or the meta data on my website isn't quite right.

I dont want all my people who see the blog article share to click it and get sent to the app (if it's installed on their phone) ... I want them to go to the website and be able to read and share the article.

has anyone ever seen this and solved it?

Thanks!

Comment: The HTML source code of your blog articles contains the meta tags that are responsible for deep linking ...

Answer (score 0):

It was the al:web:url meta tag that I had on the site pointing at the itunes link for the app. I removed that and re-scraped my links in facebook's sharing debugger and now links to my website are opening correctly on my phone.